# How to Invoke-Expression to call a function or script with variables?

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I get the an invalid path error with this script:

```
$buildZIP= 'starmatic'
echo $buildZIP
$command = ”\\XXXXXXXXXX\L$\Gopi_Prod_App\ToZipNew.ps1 $buildZIP”
Invoke-Expression -Command $command
```

This is `ToZipNew.ps1`:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string]$build
)
echo "$build"
$S = "L:\Gopi_Prod_App\$build\App_Data\*"
$D = "\Gopi_Prod_App\Starmatic_UI.zip"

echo $S
echo $D

Get-ChildItem "$S" | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$D" -Verbose
#Compress-Archive -Path "$S" -CompressionLevel Fastest -DestinationPath "$D"
```

Error I am getting:

```
Compress-Archive : The path 'L:\Gopi_Prod_App' either does not exist or is not a
valid file system path.  
At \\XXXXXXXXXXX\L$\Gopi_Prod_App\ToZipNew.ps1:13 char:45 
+ ... t-ChildItem "$S" | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath "$D" -Verbose
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (L:\Gopi_Prod_App:String) [Compress-Archive], InvalidOperationException  
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArchiveCmdletPathNotFound,Compress-Archive
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Invoke-Expression` is [almost always the wrong tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/) for whatever job you have at hand. Also, it looks to me like you actually want to run the script on the *remote* host. However, your `Invoke-Expression` statement is reading the script from the remote share and executing it *locally*.

Change

```bsh
$command = ”\\XXXXXXXXXX\L$\Gopi_Prod_App\ToZipNew.ps1 $buildZIP”
Invoke-Expression -Command $command
```

into

```bsh
Invoke-Command -Computer 'XXXXXXXXXX' -ScriptBlock {
    & 'L:\Gopi_Prod_App\ToZipNew.ps1' $using:buildZIP
}
```

to run the script on the remote host XXXXXXXXXX.

If you do want to run the script locally connect the share `\\XXXXXXXXXX\L$` as a network drive `L:` and call the script from that drive:

```bsh
New-PSDrive -Name 'L' -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\XXXXXXXXXX\L$' -Persist
& 'L:\Gopi_Prod_App\ToZipNew.ps1' $buildZIP
Remove-PSDrive -Name 'L'
```